# Intellij IDEA: Pass java command arguments

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-9, java-10

I need to pass arguments after `java` but before class name at application startup in `IDEA`.

In "edit configuration" section "program arguments" adds options after class name.

I need this because of some features like `--add-modules` for java 9+. For example I want to make `IDEA` runs this*:

> `java --add-modules java.xml.ws com.pany.MainKt`

But for now it does this:

> `java com.pany.MainKt --add-modules java.xml.ws`

*All other arguments generated by `IDEA` are omitted for brevity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JVM arguments must be added to the "VM options" field:

`java <some intellij stuff> <VM options> <Main class> <Program arguments>`

Answer (score 4):

You can set the `VM options` in the `Edit configuration` pane. Those will be added before the classname.

[image]